$\phi^3$ theory renormalization (Schwartz QFT 16.1.1)
In Section 16.1.1 of Schwartz's QFT and SM, he deals with the 1-loop calculation of the $\phi\phi \to \phi\phi$ $t$-channel scattering amplitude in $\phi^3$ theory.
He gives $$M(Q) = \frac{g^2}{Q^2} \left(1 - \frac{1}{32 \pi^2} \frac{g^2}{Q^2} \ln{\frac{Q^2}{\Lambda^2}} + O(g^4)\right)\tag{16.15}$$
(eqn 16.15, where $Q = -p^2 = -t$), and I can understand the whole thing until now. But then he define a $Q$-dependent dimensionless variable $\tilde{g}^2 = \frac{g^2}{Q^2}$ and define the renormalization condition $\tilde{g}_R = M(Q_0)$.
The most confusing thing is (eqn 16.19) $$\tilde{g}^2 = \tilde{g}_R^2 + \frac{1}{32\pi^2} \tilde{g}_R^4 \ln\frac{Q_0^2}{\Lambda^2} + O(\tilde{g}_R^6).\tag{16.19}$$ Since $\tilde{g}$ is $Q$-dependent, RHS of this eqn must be $Q$-dependent. But $\tilde{g}_R$ is just the amplitude for some energy scale $Q_0$ which is not $Q$-dependent. So why can this eqn be true?
And why should we carry out the renormalization procedure on the dimensionless variable $\tilde{g}$ rather than $g$? I can understand the renormalization procedure of the $\phi^4$ theory since the coupling constant is itself dimensionless, but what about $\phi^3$ theory?
BTW, Schwartz says that $\phi^3$ theory is a little confusing, but he seems not to explain things further.

We are basically trying to do mathematics, e.g. use a power series. When you do that, you need to use dimensionless variables. As for your question about the RHS, isn't it obvious that a function can have a Taylor-expansion-like thing that starts from some point we fix, and then you integrate from that point to the actual observation point, and so the RHS has both fixed values and variable functions.

In equation (16.19), your LHS is ${\tilde g}^2 |_{Q=Q_0}$. Nothing in that equation depends on $Q$.

@Prahar That doesn't seem to be the case. Since this expansion is then used to calculate the amplitude of arbitrary $Q$.

I don't care what's being done afterward. As I understand it, the way you get (16.19) is to evaluate (16.15) at $Q=Q_0$ and then invert the series expansion. Unless you're getting (16.19) in some other way, I don't see how there can possibly be a $Q$-dependence in that equation.

1 - Notice that $\tilde{g}$ doesn't have to be $Q$ dependent as long as $g \propto Q^2$. Here we don't justify why this is the case, apart from the fact that it works, as we end up getting a finite observable (see equation 16.20).
2 - It is just convenient (although not mandatory) to do series expansions with dimensionless variables, so that all the coefficients of the series have the same dimensions. That's why we define $\tilde{g}$.
